# User reporting Library

Tags: php, reporting

I would like to build (or find) a php reporting library that I can use to allow my users to report any type of content as bad. Actually, if they could report content as good (which I guess would mean a rating system) that would be even better. So if anyone knows of a library like this I would love to hear about it.

Anyway, this is how I imagine the database working and I would like to know if this sounds correct.

1. ID - ID of row
2. USER_ID - ID of the user voting/reporting
3. ITEM_ID - UNIQUE table row ID of the item reported (post, other user, link, etc...)
4. TYPE - the name of the table this pertains to (posts, users, links, etc...)
5. DATE - datetime of report
6. VALUE - I guess this could be an UP vote or DOWN vote

By including the [TYPE] column I can use this voting system across all content types on my site instead of just one (like forum posts). By storing the user_id I can be sure that only one vote/report is cast per item per user.

Comment: This is one of those things that simple enough, and application-specific enough, that it's probably easier to build it yourself. Unless you're using a popular framework or platform, in which case, a module may exist, but you'd need to specify which framework/platform you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I went ahead and built it like I said. Frank was right, it wasn't too hard. Here is the code incase anyone else wants to use it on a MVC that supports AR styled DB calls like CodeIgniter or MicroMVC:

```
/*
 * Multi-table user voting model
 */
class votes extends model {

    public static $table = 'votes';


    function cast( $user_id = NULL, $item_id = NULL, $type = NULL, $vote = TRUE) {

        $where = array(
            'user_id'   => $user_id,
            'item_id'   => $item_id,
            'type'      => $type
        );

        //Try to fetch this row
        $row = $this->db->get_where(self::$table, $where );

        //Look for an existing vote row
        if( $row && ! empty($row[0]) ) {

            //Fetch row
            $row = $row[0];

            //If they already voted this way... then we're done!
            if( $row->vote == $vote) {
                return;
            }

            //Else update the row to the new vote
            $row->vote = $vote;
            $row->date = convert_time(time());

            $this->db->update( self::$table, $row, array('id' => $row->id) );

            return;
        }

        //Else create a new vote for this item
        $row = array(
            'user_id'   => $user_id,
            'item_id'   => $item_id,
            'type'      => $type,
            'date'      => convert_time(time()),
            'vote'      => $vote,
        );

        $this->db->insert( self::$table, $row);
    }
}
```